# Promoting certain keywords

Tags: seo, search-engines, wordpress, google-search, search-engine-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I am not a person from SEO background so its quite possible that my question might either is off topic or is not a valid one.

i have developed a web-site ([TheColorsofMySoul](http://www.thecolorsofmysoul.com)) using WordPress and its basically for writers, portal in itself contains a variety of topics.

Though i am taking care of providing good titles, descriptions as well keywords of each posts which is being published but i want to promote some specific words in general.

e.g

Site is for writers and bloggers so i want to promote some specific keywords like "online writing community" so that if some one search for such words on Google, search engine can place my site on some top results.

i know that its quite a big tasks but i am not sure how to use those words in my site so that i can able to boost the search result ranking for these words

any help/resources will really be helpful for me

Comment: This is specific to WordPress open to users... I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Christopher agree with you and moreover in addition to the keywords specific to posts being published i want to promote some specific keywords which are generic to entire portal.